# Failed to send an email in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sendmail

My code is like this :

```
public function sendMail(array $data)
    { 
        $data = explode('#', $data['id']);
        $email_from = Auth::user()->email;
        $email_to = $data[4];
        $subject = 'Send Email Test';

        $data_user = ['user_name' => $data[1], 'full_name' => $data[2].' '.$data[3] ];

        $sent = Mail::send('backend.auth.success_approved', $data_user, function ($mail) use ($email_to, $email_from, $subject)
                {
                    $mail->from($email_from)
                         ->to($email_to)
                         ->subject($subject);
                });
    }
```

My configuration in mail.php :

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'ssl://secure.emailsrvr.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => ['address' => 'myemail@chel.com', 'name' => 'myname'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'myemail@chel.com'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

There is error message :

`Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265: Connection could not be established with host ssl://secure.emailsrvr.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. #0].`

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: who is the emailsrvr ? private? gmail/yahoo/etc ??

Comment: @LeviZoesch, It is a server name used my office

Comment: TLS uses 587 port, you are using 465 which is used for ssl. That may arise some problem.

Comment: @Md.SumsuddinShojib, The same result. It's not working

Comment: I can just recommend that, you first try using gmail smtp, keeping everything same on laravel config & see whether it works or not. Then you can narrow down the area of the problem.

Comment: @Md.SumsuddinShojib, I have been using smtp gmail and it's working. But when I use host with server name : secure.emailsrvr.com. It's not working

Comment: @Md.SumsuddinShojib, I set up like this :  http://pastebin.com/1GCUPsun. There is no error, but the e-mail could not be sent

Comment: can you show us the mail section of your env file?

Comment: @Vikas, In my opinion, it does not matter without using env file. Because it was set in mail.php. I sent an email with gmail smtp with no env file, it works

Comment: Yes I know that it doesn't matter if you use env file, but I was just wondering if there were any incorrect settings in the env file.

Comment: @Vikas, I don't use file env (.env). I just set in mail.php. when I send an email with smtp gmail, it works

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I believe that for some reason the domain (secure.emailsrvr.com) of the mail server cannot be resolved.
If you are on a shared hosting you should ask your hosting provider, if you are on a dedicated server or vps you should ping the hostname and see if it can be resolved.

Comment: It seems the problem is not in the server. Because when I use codeigniter like this : http://pastebin.com/9ax3Ah8j. It's working. But, when I use laravel, It's not working.

Comment: Ok I just noticed the issue.Set the host to secure.emailsrvr.com (no ssl:// in front) and set encryption to ssl.

Comment: I set up like this : 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'secure.emailsrvr.com'), 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'). There is no error, but the e-mail could not be sent

Comment: I set up like this : http://pastebin.com/1GCUPsun. There is no error, but the e-mail could not be sent

Comment: Config seems ok.Can you see  storage/logs/laravel.log to see if there are any errors there?

Comment: There is no error. I tried it on localhost. Whether in localhost it does not work?

Comment: But when I use CodeIgniter it works. although it is in localhost

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following things, it worked for me.

1. Create an email account on the server. Now we have MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD.
2. Make the following changes to create global variables in .env file of Laravel framework.

   ```
   MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
   MAIL_HOST=yourhost
   MAIL_PORT=465
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
   MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@something.com
   MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
   ```

   Or else you can add the above changes in your config/mail.php. It'll work.

Answer (score -3):

some email parameters in laravel 5+, are defined in .env file, sometimes laravel dont recognize other parameters outside .env file, 
check first if your parameters are sent, if not try to send an email to your personal account and try to change the parameters in the .env file

Comment: According to the error message, the configuration is read and used just fine. It just seems to be incorrect.